# Static methods or broadcast receiver?

Tags: android, android-asynctask, broadcastreceiver, return-value, static-methods

I found a lot of useful answer on this great site that helped me a lot in learning app programming. Now it's my time to make a question as I cannot find something similar. Things are: I have an activity (suppose main activity) that uses a class to execute various background operation with async task. In the onPostExecute method I return values to the main activity using a public static method (es. MainActivity.setResult(asyTaskResult); my question is: is this the correct way to handle the result? Should I use a broadcast receiver? Are there any better methods to use? I'm new In posting questions and I don't really know if I made it in the correct way. I will appreciate any help or link pointing to a useful answer. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> is this the correct way to handle the result?

Probably not, as it is easy to get a memory leak that way.

> Should I use a broadcast receiver?

Probably not in the way that you are thinking.

> Are there any better methods to use?

Have the `AsyncTask` be managed by a retained fragment, and have the task talk to the fragment instance, as in [this sample app](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/Threads/AsyncTask).

Or, use an event bus, such as `LocalBroadcastManager`, Square's Otto, or greenrobot's EventBus, as in [this sample app](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/EventBus/AsyncDemo).

Comment: If i correctly understand, the way is to add a supportfragment to the main activity that do the async work. And it's possible to access methods of the main acivity from the support frag? Or maybe i understand nothing?

Comment: @user3805886: "And it's possible to access methods of the main acivity from the support frag?" -- try not to do that in the background thread (`doInBackground()` of the `AsyncTask`). It is safe to have the fragment talk its hosting activity on the main application thread (e.g., `onPostExecute()` of the `AsyncTask`).

Comment: Ok. I solved it with localbroadcast manager. Thanks for the answer